Run multiple routines simultaneously in the frequently run cron spring
I have scheduled cron which runs every 15 minutes and query all active subscribers with active plan and hits the usage fetch api for each subscriber and update the usage in the database. all this activity run by a single thread so that every cron run took 45 to 70 minutes which is very high time and subscriber is unable to see the real time usage immediately. Once cron is running and another run waits for the previous run to finish.
Can you advise any better way to handle this problem to decrease the cron time and cron run has to be finished in 15 minutes for any number of subscribers?

Can you parallelize your processing?
You don't really give enough information for anyone to advise. Let me guess, though, each "subscriber" could be processed in parallel, so you would do something like this (pseudo code):
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

subscriberUsageUpdater() {
  read subscribers
  for each subscriber:
     executorService.submit {
        process subscriber // hits the usage fetch api for each subscriber and update the usage in the database
     }
}

